fake api is not working for angular cors error
giving error for cors if i make backend then i can make cors problem solve but when i use fakeapi. How can i solve this problem for cors error
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://freeapi.gerasim.in/api/BigBasket/GetAllProducts' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
getCategory(){
   return  this.http.get(Constant.API_END_POINT + Constant.METHODS.GET_ALL_CATEGORY)
}

this is my function where i am getting api for getcategory:
 getAllCetegory(){
    this.productService.getCategory().subscribe((res:any)=>{
     try {
       this.categoryList = res.data
       console.log("hrre the",this.categoryList);
     } catch (error) {
      console.log("error hai ",error)
     }
    })
  }

this is the function where i am using this function for ts
API_END_POINT: 'https://freeapi.gerasim.in/api/BigBasket/', API_END_POINT_USER: 'http://freeapi.gerasim.in/api/User/',

Try it https://angular.dev/tools/cli/serve#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Does this answer your question? Understanding CORS

i have tried this but not working for proxy.config.json where i am mentioning https://freeapi.gerasim.in this but one of friend suggest me to download cors extension and when i do and run my problem is solved

why not make request to the API from your server instead, and then you can trigger request from angular to your server...

i had not make api for backend for backend i know how to manage cors error but i want to use online api like bigbasket
